# Vue-Chartjs not rendering graph

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-component, vue-chartjs

I am buiding a website with laravel and using the vuejs to manage the front-end. I want to display several charts through vue-chartjs but the vue-chartjs is not showing the graph even though the data is successfully passed. I have been following their website guide but the graph never displays.
[image]
My Vue Component

```
<teplate>
    <div>
      ...
    <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></line-chart>
    <button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Table from '../equipments/table.vue'
import LineChart from '../equipments/LineChart.js'
import DropDownList from '../equipments/dropdownlist.vue'
    export default {
    data () {
      return {
        datacollection: null
      }
    },
        components: {
            LineChart,
            Table,
            DropDownList
        },
    mounted () {
      this.fillData()
    },
    methods: {
      fillData () {
        this.datacollection = {
          labels: ['weqw','wewq'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
            }, 
            {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      getRandomInt () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .small {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin:  150px auto;
  }
</style>
```

my Chart.js

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

Hope could receive some hints here, thanks in advance

Comment: What version of chart.js are you using?

Comment: "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
        "vue-sidebar-menu": "^5.0.1"
    } @LeeLenalee

Comment: these are all my dependency installed from npm. both chart.js and vue-chartjs version are 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vue-chartjs` only works with v2 of `chart.js`. So you will need to downgrade chart.js to version `2.9.4` if you want to use it.

`npm i chart.js@2.9.4`